# 'Repairing Disk Errors' message: what to do?

Tags: boot

I noticed a nasty smell when playing a game on the PC: a bit like car exhaust fumes from an old car.

I posted a question asking how to stop this from happening (in order to be able to carry on playing the game) on a few forums. On one of them, I was asked what the make of the PSU was and told it may be written on the PSU, so I unscrewed the side panel of the PC in an effort to find out the brand of the PSU. In doing so, when I pulled the panel off, 1 or more things got disconnected.  I was left with a fan which had 2 disconnected plugs on: both the same size, 4 pin, one to go in, one to take in, attached to each other by a thick bunch of wires: yellow, red and green. Also, I noticed a smaller 4 pin in connector from something else and a smaller 3 pin in connector from something else. Anyway, I connected the larger 4 pin in (from the fan) into the only thing that it would seem to connect to, which was into a connector from a bunch of wires in the middle. The other 2 (into) connectors didn't seem to have any matching connectors to plug into them that I could see, so I left them unplugged. The first time I turned the PC on after this, it booted up ok, but then it would't boot up and just said 'Reboot and Select proper Boot Device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key'.

I opened the PC again and looked at it. I noticed another loose connection so I put the loose connector in.

Upon starting the PC up, it then gave the message 'Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart. We're just collecting info...'

Then it said 'Preparing Automatic Repair'

Then 'Diagnosing your PC'

Then it said 'Your PC did not start correctly. Press restart to restart your PC which can sometimes fix the problem.'

Then were 2 options: 'Restart' which just resulted in the same thing happening again and 'Advanced Options' which brought up 4 options:

1. 'Continue' (to Windows 8.1): resulted in same again
2. 'Use a device' (USB Drive, network connection or Windows Recovery DVD)
3. Troubleshoot
4. Turn off PC

Selecting option 3 gave 6 options:

1. Sys restore: tried this. Restore successful but just got same again
2. Command Prompt
3. Sys Image Recovery
4. UEFI Firmware Settings
5. Start Up Repair (tried this: didn't change anything)
6. Start Up Settings

6 had 10 options. 1 option was Use Windows Safe Mode: I selected this.  It didn't work at first but then it started up in safe mode, but I couldn't get the internet, so I rebooted and it rebooted in normal mode and then everything was fine.

However, a couple of times when starting the PC up, it did give the message 'Your PC did not start correctly. Press restart to restart your PC which can sometimes fix the problem' again, so I tried starting in safe mode again, which worked again.

Last night I was playing a different game (it wasn't causing a bad smell) and then the PC just switched off.

When I rebooted, it gave these messages:

'Preparing Automatic Repair'

Then 'Diagnosing your PC'

Then 'Repairing Disk Errors. This might take an hour.'

Then it just goes to the 'doing something' screen.

I've tried just switching the PC off, but it does the same thing every time, so now I've just left it to try to repair those disk errors and plan to actually leave it an hour or more to see if it comes back with anything.

I also noticed that one of the connectors which I couldn't see the slot for before was the Power LED and plugged it in, which worked: the power light is now working, but as I say, the PC's not booting up.

I'm just wondering what to do next a) if it comes back with something b) if it doesn't come back with anything before I switch it off (I do plan to give it a bit more than an hour at least).

Comment: Random behaviour indicates hardware error. I suppose it's PSU's fault then. Do you have any other units to try?

Comment: No I don't. Maybe I should buy a new PSU.

Comment: Maybe take computer to local shop? Maybe they will diagnose the problem? Also, can you tell from where does the smell come from?

Comment: Yes: taking it to a local shop is probably a good way to sort it. No, I haven't been able to find out where the smell came from, but I think the PSU as it occurred when the PC was working hard.

Comment: Usually the smell isn't like you said it was... Strange. Does the fan in the PSU work?

Comment: All fans were working fine, as far as I know. The smell only occurred when playing 1 game and another game with multiple add-ons (with just 1 add-on, playing the second game didn't cause any problems). Maybe my description of the smell is inaccurate.

Comment: @LittleHelper: actually the smell might have been the neighbour's lawnmower, but the PC still isn't working, as I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the hard drive failed, so I had it replaced and the PC works again. After having it fixed though, the PC shutdown again while I was using it and I thought 'Oh no! Not again.' Thankfully though, it was the power strip: switching to a different one I found that the PC was still ok.